# How do you run a Django development server at the command prompt?

Tags: python, django

trying to run the development server as directed by the django book 2.0. Heres what im doing so far:

1) cd into the directory containing python
2) run the python interpreter using the "python" command 
3) Import django with the python interpreter 
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/

Now step 4 should be cd into the mysite directory and then run the command "python manage.py 
runserver"

My question though is how do you cd into another directory while the python interpreter in running 
in the command prompt so i can use the command to run the development server?

If somebody could just list step by step as to how they run the development server from the command prompt or explain to me what im doing wrong, it would be very much appreciated as i have been trying to figure this out forever.

Btw directories i change to in order "Python27>mysite". mysite is in the Python 27 folder. Python 27 contains the python files which includes the python.exe file and mysite contains the project which include manage.py file.

Comment: run `python manage.py runserver` from system shell, after you have moved into the project directory. you never do it from python interpreter.

Answer (score 32):

Change in your django project and run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

that's all!

Comment: thanks but how do you change into the project from the python interpreter? python needs to be running in order to run that command.

Comment: @user: no it's not. This is a `cmd` command, just a regular `cd`. Only *then* do you run `manage.py` through the Python interpreter

Comment: No! It doesn't! There is no magic :)

Comment: @eli so are you saying 1) fire up command prompt and cd all the way into the project folder 2) start python interpreter 3) run manage.py runserver? at step 2 when i try to start python using the command it says its not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file. what could be the issue?

Comment: @user: python probably isn't installed/configured properly on your system - this is a whole other issue. What you should do is exactly what @programmersbook said - open prompt, `cd` into your project dir and run the command he pasted

Comment: @user560117: Please post **THAT** as your question.  Don't ask random stuff. Please **Update** the question to post the command you **actually** typed and the **actual** error you **actually** got.  Please **focus** on what **actually** happened.  Please **update** your question to show what your **actually** did.

Comment: for python 3 you just type: python3 manage.py runserver. For all the updated peeps :).

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute the "cd" command directly while in the Python interpreter. You need to first exit the interpreter by calling the exit() method. (Just write exit() into the interpreter and press enter). The revised steps taking this into consideration would be:

1. cd into the directory containing python
2. run the python interpreter using the "python" command
3. Import django with the python interpreter
4. exit interpreter
5. cd into mysite directory and type python manage.py runserver

Comment: Well, you definitely *can* change the current directory from inside Python, with `os.chdir`

Comment: You are right, Eli. But, I thought that would complicate things for user560117.

Comment: Or you could install ipython which lets you use cd.

Comment: thanks xavier. i tried the steps provided and i cd into mysite and typed python manage.py runserver but im getting this:"python" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: I have edited my original question to show the directories i change into and what they contain. Hopefully that will aid. Thanks everyone for your help thus far.

Comment: This is an issue regarding the configuration of the PATH variable. If you're not in the directory of the python.exe file, you won't be able to use the python command in the cmd prompt until you include it in your PATH variable.  Please read this: http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/200f07/setpath.html